# How can I have a generic IEnumerable property

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to do something like this in my class:

```
public IEnumerable<T> ItemsImported { get; set; }
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Have you tried it?

Comment: What are you intending to do with it? It's possible... might not be the best idea though

Comment: where do you wanted  to use it ?

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**

Make the class generic:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> ItemsImported { get; set; }
}
```

**Option 2**

Make a pair of generic methods:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetItemsImported<T>()
{
    // ...
}

public void SetItemsImported<T>(IEnumerable<T> value)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a generic class, then yes, it's possible:

```
public class Foo<T> 
{
    public IEnumerable<T> ItemsImported { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is but your class also has to be generic then.

```
public class YourClass<T>()
{
   public IEnumerable<T> ItemsImported { get; set; }
}
```

Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

Well the real question should be: is your class generic? Or said differently: what's is your intent for using generic template? If your class has to be generic then the proposed solutions fit otherwise I would recommend one of the two:

- your `items` match against an interface then `IEnumerable<IMyItem>` would be appropriate
- your `items` have no common type or interface then `IEnumerable<object>` should do the job. You will have to check the type of the actual objects in the calling code of course.